# why Handlebars {{body}} doesnt receive my tags as html?

Tags: javascript, express, handlebars.js

I dont understand why doesnt this show the example in the other file

This is for a CRUD with Mongo Express and Node, and i was starting and checking, and i saw that this doesnt work, so i stop, the thing is, i dont understand why

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>CRUD M.E.N</title>
</head>
<body>
    <p>Navegacion</p>

    {{ body }}

    <p>Pie</p>

</body>
</html>
```

routing code

```
const router = require('express').Router();

router.get('/', (req, res) =>{
    res.render('index')
})
router.get('/about', (req, res) =>{
    res.render('about');
})
module.exports = router;

index.js code
<p>HOLAA</p>
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pf8OE.png

i expect that body shows the things that was in the index and about files

Answer (score 0):

The solution was just put another bracket... Damn, im so.. xd